# How to change the frame(fixed/target) of hokuyo node?

Tags: ros, rviz, laser, frame, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the launch file

```
 <launch>
    <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_node">
        <remap from="/laser" to="/base_laser" />
    </node>
 </launch>
```

I run the command :

```
 rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find hokuyo_node`/hokuyo_test.vcg
```

It shows the frame /laser not /base_laser.

[image: image description]

1. How to change it when run the launch file? Because in other nodes use the other name.
2. What difference between fixed and target frame?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10657/how-to-change-the-frame(fixed/target)-of-hokuyo-node?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am not sure you can change a parameter using remap, you could change the name of a topic for example, in hokuyo_node you can change the topic "scan". [Click here for more information](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/remap)
This topic publishes LaserScan messages, which contain an element called "frame_id" which is also a parameter of the node and it is set to "laser" by default.

1. To change this you can use the dynamic reconfigure

   rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui

or set the parameter in the launch file adding the line

```
<param name="frame_id" value="/base_laser"/>
```

2. Check the [rviz Coordinate Frames](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide#Coordinate_Frames) out
   I hope this will help you!

(edit) After seen [mbj](http://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/)'s reply
Also you can change the Fixed frame, clicking and editing the text.

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2011-07-20**:
because you have to change it in both places, reconfigure_gui changes the frame_id in the LaserScan messages published and also change the fixed_frame in rviz (or in the .vcg file, which is the rviz configuration) which tells the program which frame_id is the "base" or the "world"

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
Why I use reconfigure_gui to change /laser to /base_laser, it doesn't work when I opne rviz : rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find hokuyo_node`/hokuyo_test.vcg ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can edit the hokuyo_test.vcg and rename **Fixed Frame=/laser to Fixed Frame=/base_laser**.

Answering to your question between fixed and target frame differences, you can take a look of [this wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide#The_Fixed_Frame).

---

Originally posted by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) with karma: 197 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1